# How do I reproduce this type of table in Stata?

Tags: stata

My data currently looks like this:

```
    Group   Team    Ind. 1990 1991
    Group 1  Blue    a   1   1
    Group 1  Blue    b   1   1
    Group 1  Blue    c       1
    Group 1  Green   a   1   1
    Group 1  Green   b   1   1
    Group 1  Green   c   1   1
    Group 1  Orange  a       1
    Group 1  Orange  b   1   1
    Group 1  Orange  c   1   1
    Group 2  Black   a   1   1
    Group 2  Black   b   1   1
    Group 2  Black   c   1   1
    Group 3  Grey    a   1  
    Group 3  Grey    b       1
    Group 3  Grey    c       1
    Group 3  Yellow  a   1   1
    Group 3  Yellow  b   1   1
    Group 3  Yellow  c
```

And I want to summarize it into this type of table:

```
                                                        1990  1991
Group 1  No. of Teams with all ind. (i.e. a,b,AND c)     1      3
Group 1  No. of Teams missing a value in a,b,OR c        2      0
Group 2  No. of Teams with all ind. (i.e. a,b,AND c)     1      1
Group 2  No. of Teams missing a value in a,b,OR c        0      0
Group 3  No. of Teams with all ind. (i.e. a,b,AND c)     0      0
Group 3  No. of Teams missing a value in a,b,OR c        2      2
```

I tried reshaping my data (and having Year as one variable), and then using the egen command:

```
egen test=count(Team), by (Group Year Team)
```

But then it was only counting the total number of rows which are complete for each Year and Group. It did not considering the uniques team in any case.

Comment: It is not completely clear what your variables are: for example, 1990 and 1991 are not legal variable names. Please use `dataex` (SSC) to give an example that makes variable names and types explicit and can be copy-and-pasted into Stata.

Comment: Good point. Ill edit my post and use dataex to post an example of the Stata code as soon as I can access Stata again (FYI, I can quickly tell you that the variables in question are four: "Group", "Team", "Ind.", "1990" and "1991"). In any case, I should point out that the first table I posted is in Excel, but I want to import it into Stata to then generate the second table.

Comment: @NickCox Roberto Ferrer, below, wrote the input code for creating my desired variables in Stata. Hope that makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose in your example data, blanks are missings and the corresponding variables are numeric. Then something similar to what you want can be achieved with:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
group str10 team  str1 ind y1990 y1991
 1  Blue    a   1   1
 1  Blue    b   1   1
 1  Blue    c   .    1
 1  Green   a   1   1
 1  Green   b   1   1
 1  Green   c   1   1
 1  Orange  a    .   1
 1  Orange  b   1   1
 1  Orange  c   1   1
 2  Black   a   1   1
 2  Black   b   1   1
 2  Black   c   1   1
 3  Grey    a   1  .
 3  Grey    b    .   1
 3  Grey    c    .   1
 3  Yellow  a   1   1
 3  Yellow  b   1   1
 3  Yellow  c  .    .
end

list, sepby(group team)

*----- (similar to) what you want -----

// set years
local years 1990 1991

// number of teams per -group-
bysort group (team) : egen numteam = total(team != team[_n-1])

// comply with "and" condition
foreach y of local years {
    bysort group team (y`y') : gen and`y' = y`y'[1] == y`y'[_N]
}

// compute counts of "and" conditions
collapse (first) and* numteam, by(group team)
collapse (sum) and* (first) numteam, by(group)

// compute counts of "exclusive or" conditions
foreach y of local years {
    gen xor`y' = numteam - and`y'
}

// print
drop numteam
list
```

For any year, and `group team` combination, notice the strategy to check if all individuals are present: `sort` the indicator variable and if the first and last observations are the same, then all individuals are present (discard for the moment the case where all values are missing). If they are not the same, meaning a `1` in the first observation and a `.` in the last, there is at least one individual not present.

(I leave to you the exercise of getting that into the *exact* structure you originally ask for.)

But the usual recommendation is to work with data in *long* form, because most statistical analysis in Stata is easier this way. To do so, `reshape` first, and then do the rest:

```
<snip>

*----- what you want -----

// reshape data
gen i = _n
reshape long y, i(i) j(year)

// number of teams per -group-
bysort group (team) : egen numteam = total(team != team[_n-1])

// comply with "and" condition
rename (ind y) (id indicat)
bysort year group team (indicat) : gen and = indicat[1] == indicat[_N]

// compute counts of "and" conditions
collapse (first) and numteam, by(year group team)
collapse (sum) and (first) numteam, by(year group)

// compute counts of "exclusive or" conditions
gen xor = numteam - and

// pretty print
drop numteam
order group
sort group year
list, sepby(group)
```

The first piece of code outputs:

```
. list

     +-----------------------------------------------+
     | group   and1990   and1991   xor1990   xor1991 |
     |-----------------------------------------------|
  1. |     1         1         3         2         0 |
  2. |     2         1         1         0         0 |
  3. |     3         0         0         2         2 |
     +-----------------------------------------------+
```

and the second:

```
. list, sepby(group)

     +--------------------------+
     | group   year   and   xor |
     |--------------------------|
  1. |     1   1990     1     2 |
  2. |     1   1991     3     0 |
     |--------------------------|
  3. |     2   1990     1     0 |
  4. |     2   1991     1     0 |
     |--------------------------|
  5. |     3   1990     0     2 |
  6. |     3   1991     0     2 |
     +--------------------------+
```

Finally, watch out for teams that have all missing values for any year, e.g. team **Red** in 1990, below:

```
     +--------------------------------------+
     | group     team   ind   y1990   y1991 |
     |--------------------------------------|
  1. |     1     Blue     a       1       1 |
  2. |     1     Blue     b       1       1 |
  3. |     1     Blue     c       .       1 |
     |--------------------------------------|
  .
  .
  .
     |--------------------------------------|
 19. |     4      Red     a       .       . |
 20. |     4      Red     b       .       1 |
 21. |     4      Red     c       .       1 |
     |--------------------------------------|
 22. |     4    White     a       1       1 |
 23. |     4    White     b       1       1 |
 24. |     4    White     c       .       . |
     +--------------------------------------+
```

as these are treated as if all individuals are present.

You need to establish how the counts behave in such cases. One way to adjust is to use

```
bysort year group team (indicat) : gen and = indicat[1] == indicat[_N]  ///
    & !missing(indicat[1])
```

instead of the corresponding original. After `sort`ing, we only need to check if the first value is non-missing in order to discard the case that all values are missing.

### Edit

Running the code with the modified line, along with my original example data, plus a fourth group with a team of all missings (see above), results in:

```
. list, sepby(group)

     +--------------------------+
     | group   year   and   xor |
     |--------------------------|
  1. |     1   1990     1     2 |
  2. |     1   1991     3     0 |
     |--------------------------|
  3. |     2   1990     1     0 |
  4. |     2   1991     1     0 |
     |--------------------------|
  5. |     3   1990     0     2 |
  6. |     3   1991     0     2 |
     |--------------------------|
  7. |     4   1990     0     2 |
  8. |     4   1991     0     2 |
     +--------------------------+
```

That's what I expect, according to the logic I defined: if the team has all missing values, then count it with the *exclusive or* conditions. If you want to follow a different logic, you need to i) spell it out, and ii) translate it to code.

### Edit 2

If, as in your comment, the indicator variables can take on any positive value, you can generalize the rule for counting *and* conditions. Add a fifth group to the example data:

```
.
.    
.
    |--------------------------------------|
25. |     5     Blue     a       1       . |
26. |     5     Blue     b       1       . |
27. |     5     Blue     c       1       . |
28. |     5    Green     a       2       . |
29. |     5    Green     b       2       . |
30. |     5    Green     c       .       . |
31. |     5   Orange     a       3       . |
32. |     5   Orange     b       2       . |
33. |     5   Orange     c      55       . |
    +--------------------------------------+
```

and modify the corresponding line to:

```
bysort year group team (indicat) : gen and = !missing(indicat[_N])
```

I only check the last value (`_N`), because after sorting, if the last value is not missing, then there are no missings at all.

Check `help subscripting` and `help bysort`, if not familiarized with the concepts.

Comment: Thanks, Roberto. It worked great, except, as you pointed out, in those cases where "teams that have all missing values for any year". I adjusted the code using "bysort year group team (indicat) : gen and = indicat[1] == indicat[_N]  & !missing(indicat[1])" as you suggested, but that did not quite make it. I did not quite implement this part "After sorting, we only need to check if the first value is non-missing in order to discard the case that all values are missing." since I wasn't sure how to. Do you mind explaining?

Comment: I edited my original answer to express more explicitly what I meant with the modified line. There is nothing I wrote that needs implementation. The sentence you quote is meant to (tersely?) explain why I didn't check for missings in the first **and the last value**, but did only so for the first value.

Comment: You report that the modified line of code "did not quite make it". That's impossible to interpret, as it could mean anything. As posted within the edit (and also before the edit), you need to decide what to do in those cases, i.e. define some logic to handle cases where a team has all values missing. All I can infer is that my logic of counting those cases as `xor`s, does not correspond with your (implicit) logic.

Comment: Turns out we were on the same page in terms of logic.The underlying issue wasn't related to that, but rather to the fact that my example was disingenuous. Apologies for this. Where I describe what my data looks like I used "1" to represent any cell with data, but in reality this number can be any positive number greater than zero. If you run your example for only one year and one region and substitute the "1s" for other numbers ([like this](http://notepad.cc/raodaphi88)) the code doesn't work as I'd like it to. Any suggestions?

Comment: Find a suggestion in my answer under **Edit 2**.